# Unloading a ByteArray in Actionscript 3 Android

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, resize, size

Does anyone know how to forcefully unload a `ByteArray` from memory in AS3?

I have tried (without success):

```
byteArray.length = 0;
byteArray = new ByteArray();
```

and

```
for ( var i:int=0; i&lt;byteArray.length; i++ ) {
    byteArray[i] = null;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Px is different from DP. You can check here for a converter: http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/.

Comment: But do I really have to create a copy of my original layout for each one of them. I mean, I have like 100-200 of them. And all of them contain the same image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all dp != px

Read this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You do not have to provide different layouts for different screen sizes, however the possibility of say a tablet displaying more data over a phone is there - so you may want to give the user more options or show the navigation constantly.

AS for handling images, at the above link, you should take the xhdpi/hdpi size and recreate it at x0.75 (ldpi), normal (mdpi), x1.5 (hdpi) and x2.0 (xhdpi). You then can reference the single image 'R.drawable.logo' and the phone will pick the most appropriate available resource from the relevant drawable folder (e.g. drawable-hdpi).

Plug moment, we have build an alpha tool to do the resizing based on c# .net 2.0 we will publish Alpha version at http://www.wiseman-designs.com/downloads/android-icon-creator/, EDIT: which is free for everyone for anything - source will be released after xmas.

Comment: Let say I have an Image that has the original size of 250 by 400, should I make it bigger and store it on (e.g. drawable-hdpi)? If so, how would I know the right size so it would not look like it has been stretched?

Comment: First can I ask why i have been -1'd? I didn't think I had said anything wrong? The tool I mentioned is free for all to use for any project type. Just don't want it to keep happening :(

You should check out the AQuery library it handles a lot of this for you including resizing. I would say its easiest to simply test on a device. Once the image is positioned correctly and at the right size then your scaled down images in MDPI...etc shoudl ook right on other devices.

Comment: It was not me that voted you down, I can't even do that because my reputation is only 25, I guess it was Bill Gary. Thanks for your info by the way, I'll try it!

Comment: Good luck Leon, I just did not want SO to start penalising me on an ongoing basis.

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by Screen Compatibility Mode

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html

The only way to avoid it is to use the different drawable folders, but you can just do medium, which is the default, and xlarge and just have Screen Compatibility Mode handle the rest